# How to reuse target in Makefile?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

Basically, I want to make this code  in file **Makefile** executable:

```
targ: file1.cpp
    g++ file1.cpp -o file1

targ: file2.cpp
    g++ file2.cpp -o file2

targ: file3.cpp
    g++ file3.cpp -o file3
```

I know that I could combine it into something like this:

```
targ: file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
    g++ file1.cpp -o file1
    g++ file2.cpp -o file2
    g++ file3.cpp -o file3
```

But I want it to only run the corresponding line when the corresponding file is updated. How do I do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In a makefile rule, whatever you put in the left hand side of `:` is the product/result of running the commands below. In your example, you are saying that `targ` product is made in three different ways, which is confusing because the way of creating `targ` is ambiguous. What you probably wanted to say is that in order to succesfully build `targ`, you need to create three executables `file1` `file2` and `file3`, each built using their corresponding `.cpp` files.

For that purpose you can rely on the [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html). For a C++ executable, the implicit recipe is going to look for a `.o` file with the same name, and for that `.o` file it is going to look for several file name alternatives including `.cpp`.

So basically something like this should be enough:

```
CXX=g++
targ: file1 file2 file3
```

The implicit recipe uses [variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#Implicit-Variables) such as `CXX` to define the C++ compiler, `CPPFLAGS` to define the preprocessor flags (`-I`, `-D`, etc.) the compiler and linker flags `CXXFLAGS` `LDFLAGS` and what libraries you are going to link against `LDLIBS`.

If you do not want to rely on implicit rules, you can create a pattern recipe and use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html):

```
target: file1 file2 file3

%: %.cpp
  g++ $^ -o $@
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set up the relations right.

Example:

```
targ: file1 file2 file3

file1: file1.cpp
    g++ file1.cpp -o file1

file2: file2.cpp
    g++ file2.cpp -o file2

file3: file3.cpp
    g++ file3.cpp -o file3
```

That says:

if you want to build `targ` ( you should also make it PHONY ), make sees that you will build `file1` `file2` and `file3`. And for this, you have the explicit rules. Thats it!